# Nodejs ошибка местоположения

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

Скачал Nodejs с сайта и распаковал. захожу в `bin` и выполняю `./npm install -g programm` в итоге мне выдаёт:

`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Вариант сделать `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` не подходит, так как нет прав. Может кто знает как прописать путь до местоположения Nodejs в моей домашней директории.

Comment: Получит права никак, и установить через yum тоже никак

Comment: Прописать пути до файлов ноды в `.bashrc` не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё было предельно просто, решается добавлением в $PATH

Моя команда: `export PATH=/home/lul/minir/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin:$PATH`